# How to do NFC(Near Field Communication) in android

Tags: android

I just want to scan details from my bussiness card through NFC into my native app(like address,name,company name) programmatically. I dont have much idea on this.What are the necessary steps i need to set up?How could i begin to do this app in android?

And one more,QR scanner is something different from NFC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking NFC is a radio communication technology while QR is a image communication technology, so although they have some things like channel coding in common, they are available in mobile phones through quite different APIs.

In terms of functionally, NFC has more features than QR, but QR can be made to work on more devices (at this point in time).

I've actually made an app which supports both NFC and QR. You can get yourself started using the [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) (by yours truly) and [XZing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Answer (score 0):

NFC Android Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

QRCode is a 2-dimensional barcode. [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library.

Barcodes are different from NFC Tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on NFC, the basic things you'll need is an NFC enabled phone and a tag.. I hope you're aware of this.. Secondly, you should go through [this link here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html). It gives you a basic idea of what NFC is and you can build on that.. Everything you want to know about Android NFC has been described there.

As far as QR is concerned, it's not the same as NFC.. But one thing I'd like to say here is that using QR for a project over NFC would bring down the cost since QR doesn't need extra hardware support like NFC does. But if you want to do something new, then NFC could be "the thing" you're searching for.

Hope this answers your question. If you're looking for something more, then please mention that too so that I can edit my answer later on..